# AWS lambda building external dependency libraries in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, lambda, scikit-learn

I am trying to create an AWS lambda function using Python. Instead of an inline function I want a create a zip deployment package and then upload it in my AWS environment. I have my source code in test.py file and other dependencies like numpy, sklearn and so on in the same folder as my source code is.

I am facing an error when I test my lambda function.

> **Unable to import module 'test': No module named
>   'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
>   ___________________________________________________________________________ Contents of /var/task/sklearn/__check_build: setup.py
>
>   __pycache__               _check_build.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
>   __init__.py
>   ___________________________________________________________________________ It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly. If you have
>   installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget to build the
>   package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or `make` in
>   the source directory. If you have used an installer, please check that
>   it is suited for your Python version, your operating system and your
>   platform.**

Here is my python source code which resides in test.py

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 is " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 is " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 is " + event['key3']) 
    return event
```

I am facing a similar issue if I import numpy in my source code. (cannot import multiarray)

I am installing every library using `pip install numpy/scikit-learn -t /path/to/mydir/`.

[Here is the folder structure after I use pip install commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irHN9.jpg)

Kindly help me resolve the issue. Thanks !!

Comment: [Using Scikit-Learn In AWS Lambda](https://serverlesscode.com/post/deploy-scikitlearn-on-lamba)

Answer (score 7):

There are likely two issues here:

1. Python packages which have `C` bindings need to be built (`pip install`) on a machine with the same architecture as that which Lambda functions run (i.e., Linux)
2. With AWS Lambda, you are responsible for managing Python's path so it can find your dependencies.  You likely need to update the path at runtime.

To solve #1, I use the official Python Docker image.

```
docker run --rm -it \
        -v `pwd`:/code \
        python:2 bash
```

Now, whenever you do a `pip install -t lib numpy` or the like, you will get the correct `.so` files.  The trick here is using the volume argument (`-v`) so that the when you shut the container down the `lib` directory is preserved on your host machine.

To solve 2, I always structure my serverless/lambda project like this:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── handler.py
├── lib
│   └── numpy
└── serverless.yml
```

That is, all of my dependencies go inside `lib`.

```
pip install -t lib numpy
```

At the top of `handler.py`, I always have these 4 lines:

```
import os
import sys

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(CWD, "lib"))

# now it's ok to import extra libraries
import numpy as np
```

*After* the `sys.path.insert`, any imports for your packages will work.

Comment: I am trying to use the solution 1. I have my libraries built on python docker image. How do I save the zip files and view them on my windows machine ?

Comment: See my note about the `-v` argument. You may need to reference the Docker documentation for Windows. https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: `whenever you do a pip install -t lib numpy or the like, you will get the correct .so files` -> 

This is just not true

Comment: @Jeremy Can you show me of an example of that not working? Using a Ubuntu Docker image it hasn't failed me yet. I'd honestly love to see a real world example of this failing...I have yet to find it.

Comment: @brianz psycopg2 needs the header files to compile and the .so in runtime (libpq). If you don't have libpq in your base system it's not gonna work, since psycopg2 is a python wrapper

Comment: I've used this technique in multiple production systems without issue. While this may be true, using an Ubuntu Docker image to build psycopg2 works just fine.